# Developing for the Notification Hub on Mac OS - NodeJS/.Net Core support seems deprecated

Tags: macos, azure, azure-notificationhub

I am doing investigations into the Notification Hub in Azure. We are using Mac OS for our development environment, so only have use of .Net Core and Node JS SDKs.

[This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46921298/is-microsoft-azure-notificationhubs-1-0-9-compatible-with-net-core-2-0) and [this one](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/218849-notification-hubs/suggestions/16417780-microsoft-azure-notificationhubs-add-support-for) suggest that there is no option for developing against this without being able to use .Net Framework 4.6.1.

We have managed to develop a POC using the [old NodeJS tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-nodejs-push-notification-tutorial) (which seems incomplete, as it didn't work out of the box) however, we don't want to use that in production if it is going to be made obsolete within 6 months.

Can someone please inform me of the correct way to integrate with the notification hub via a 'back end' without using .Net 4.6.1. Is the only option to use azure functions with output to notification hubs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will deploy a new version of the .net SDK supporting .net core very soon.

Comment: That’s great @Karl. Is there any pre-release builds we could use in the mean time to develop against?

Comment: @MarkMcGookin We just released the preview version. You can find it here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.NotificationHubs/2.0.0-preview1
We'd love to get your feedback!